# Pure MVVM with SwiftUI & CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, architecture, swiftui

I'm looking for some architectural guidance.

I see much confusion online with regard to MVVM and where properties and responsibilities should live.

In a nutshell I understand MVVM as:

`Model`: holds underlying data, should be portable, completely decoupled from `View` related items

`View` : View related item that specifies layout of UI

`ViewModel` : View related item that facilitates update of model (intents), and formats model data for View to display.

...I think that's a succinct description of the pattern.

My questions are, with MVVM in iOS/SwiftUI, where should data models be instantiated and where should properties like `CLLocationManager` live?

For example:

- I've seen advice to put `CLLocationManager` in the AppDelegate (as it has global scope), however many articles state it should live as a property of the `ViewModel`.
- I've spoken with Apple Engineering (WWDC 2020), and they indicated the Data model itself should house a reference to this object and populate itself.
- Many times I've seen the data model instantiated inside the `ViewModel`.

**So my question is, from a pure MVVM perspective, using a simple CoreLocation app as a concrete example, and assuming a simple Model that stores `CLLocation` objects, where would you *instantiate* the model, and which class would have a the `CLLLocationManager` as a property?**

Comment: To those trying to close as "opinion based", I'm not looking for opinions. I'm looking for authoritative answers from an academic perspective. Pls read the question properly, rather than trying to increase your meta quota for the day.

Comment: I would use a LocationServiceProtocol, implemented by a LocationService class, that I will inject in the view model. The LocationService class has the responsibility to instantiate the Location model and has the CLLocationManager property.

Comment: Makes sense @FrancescoDeliro - so I the model would be accessed through the LocationService property, that the viewModel owns?

Comment: If you want to add as an answer I will upvote and accept...

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro, I guess in essence, we are saying the viewModel can ultimately own a reference to the CoreLocation Manager, and the viewModel will own a reference to the underlying Model...

Comment: In a certain way yes, but in this way you have a better separation of concerns, the LocationService has one responsibility and it is independent. And it’s correct, the view model will receive the model data directly from the service.

Comment: I would suggest making a manager class which handles the Location. This class should be a Observable Object, which you will use in your View. When Location changes, updates getting send to the View. See a good example here https://adrianhall.github.io/swift/2019/11/05/swiftui-location/

Comment: Thanks for input @davidev. Only issue with that approach is View is directly talking to model and not using viewmodel to make changes. In fact there is no model really as view is just owning location service. So view is coupled to app logic. That’s not a good idea right?

Comment: @Woodstock Yes you are totally correct. I just read about MVVM. It looks like that it would be clever to create it in the ViewModel. I think it depends aswell, how you use that Location data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a **Service-Oriented architecture** approach. You can have your `LocationServiceProtocol`, implemented by a `LocationService` class, that you can inject in the view model. This class has the responsibility to instantiate your `Location` model and has the `CLLocationManager` property. In this way you can handle the interaction between the high and lower level implementations.

Comment: one last thought, this approach the viewModel is changing model without request from view. It does it based on its own ownership of location manager. Does that not violate MVVM?

Comment: Happy to contribute @Woodstock. If I understood your question correctly, the view should request the update of the location information and handling it in a proper way. The view model will listen for the update through the service and communicates back to the view.